# Java - Multiple Objects controlled by Timer (for a Game)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I'm currently working on a small game that consisted of a few targets that pop up at random for various amounts of time. The actual game will get it's I/O from a circuit board since the targets are physical.

My problem is that currently I have a java.util.Timer that fire's off every 2 seconds. Once it is triggered a random target will be displayed (which works fine so far). The problem is that I want to display the targets for a random number of seconds between 1-5 whilst the timer is still running and setting off other targets.

I get no errors and the targets display but never disappear. I guess it's some sort of Thread issue and that maybe since I'm using **this.*** the Target objects are just somehow getting lost in the nether! After searching around the questions here I have come up with this:

```
public class Target implements Runnable(){

  ...

    public void displayFor(int seconds){
        this.display();

        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(this,time,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        this.setDisplayed(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.destroy();
    }

}
```

Basically the initial game timer (that sets of the Targets display) calls the **displayFor(2)** method which runs the targets run method after the time passed. The Targets still won't disappear though.

I have tried a number of different ways of doing this like the **displayFor()** setting off another java.util.Timer and I also had a go at using the Quartz library (which to be honest seemed like overkill anyway) and still can't get it to work. Since there are no error messages I'm really stuck with this one.

I've haven't included a lot of the code because I don't think it's that relevant but if you guys need more information to help just let me know :)

Comment: When you draw them, are you clearing the canvas each time? Or are you just drawing them when they appear.

Comment: @glowcoder I'm not drawing anything, the target's are physical object's in the real world so when I display then I'm sending output to a circuit board

Comment: You should not create a new executor on every displayFor() call. Make it a class member and re-use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working. Here's the correct code for anyone in a similar situation.

```
public class Target{

private Timer timer;

   ...

   public void displayFor(int seconds) {
     // send the output
     BoardInterface.SetDigitalChannel(this.getId());

     // calculate the delay
     long time = seconds * 1000;

     // create a new timer and schedule the new task
     timer = new Timer();
     timer.schedule(new TargetTimer(this), time);

     this.setDisplayed(true);
  }
}

class TargetTimer extends TimerTask{
   Target target;

   public TargetTimer(Target t){
       this.target = t;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
       target.destroy();
   }

}
```

Not sure if this is a good way of doing it but it works. If you notice anything that could be improved please let me know. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should tell us what the `display` method does.

Are you **un**-displaying the target in the `destroy`/destructor code?

I'd recommend, **instead** of `void display()`:

```
public void setDisplayed(boolean display){
  if(display) {
    ///... do appropriate circuit output to turn on target
  } else {
    /// ... do appropriate circuit output to turn off target
  }
}
```

and of course

```
public void run(){
  setDisplayed(false);
  destroy();
}
```

Comment: I have actually just figured it out and got it all working but I can't answer my own question for another 6 hours because of my reputation points. I actually did create the setDisplay() method your talking about too! Thanks for your help and everyone else as well. I'll answer the question with my solution when I can.